# Insert a link into php crashes my site

Tags: php

I am faceing the problem, that my `$link` is not displayed. If I insert the lines described below, the site won't load anymore. The following code works properly.

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE user_level = 1 ")) {

        /* determine number of rows result set */
        $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

        printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
        }

    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    printf ("Adminpanel");

        $result->close();


    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

When I add this line

```
$link = 'AdminLayout.php';
    printf ("<a href="' .$link. '">Adminpanel </a>");
```

instead of

```
printf ("Adminpanel");
```

nothing works anymore. What have I done wrong?

Comment: try this 

    $link = 'AdminLayout.php';
        printf ("<a href=" .$link. ">Adminpanel </a>");

Comment: Is this code a copy&paste? Because you are missing the `'` in `'psw,`

Comment: Syntax highlighting is showing you have errors. and please stop reposting the same question over and over and over again; you are spamming Stack. One I remember closing and you deleted where you were mixing MySQL APIs/functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: **its a quotes problem**. if you need  double quotes`""` with href try with single quotes`'` at start and end.

```
$link = 'AdminLayout.php';
    printf ('<a href="' .$link. '">Adminpanel </a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error

```
printf ("<a href="' .$link. '">Adminpanel </a>");
```

should be

```
printf ("<a href='" .$link. "'>Adminpanel </a>");
```

you have your quotation in wrong order.

Btw. if you get a blank page, you might turn error reporting on.
Put this at the beginning of your script.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```